# Can't update through association: Record not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, associations

I cannot update my model setup with `Rails` on `Postgres DB`.  The `RecordNotFound` in `AccountsController#edit`.

I have tried to call the form from different ways w/o success.

Update 1:  the form call in was modified to

```
                <% if current_user.accounts.first.present? %>
            <li class="list-group-item"><%= link_to "Account data",edit_account_path(@account, current_user) %></li>
            <% end %>
```

Update 2:  Modification changed to:

```
            <% if current_user.accounts.first.present? %>
            <li class="list-group-item"><%= link_to "Account data",edit_account_path(current_user.accounts.first) %></li>
            <% end %>
```

Models:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  # associations
  has_many :accounts_users
  has_many :users, :through => :accounts_users
  has_one :company 
end

class AccountsUser < ApplicationRecord
  # associations
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :account
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  # associations 
 has_many :accounts_users
 has_many :accounts, :through => :accounts_users
 has_one :company, :through => :accounts_users 
end
```

The account controller relevant actions are the following:

```
 # POST /accounts
 # POST /accounts.json
 def create
 # create a new user if none exists
   if !current_user.present?
     build_resource(sign_in_params)
     account = Account.find_or_create_by(org_name: params[:user] [:account])
   else
# add the account for an existing user
     @account = current_user.accounts.new(account_params)
   end

# when a user account is create, add a company for that account
  # create a default account and company
     if resource.save
       resource.accounts << account
       if resource.current_account.companies.empty?
         company =   resource.current_account.companies.create({company_name: params[:user] [:account] })
       else
         company = resource.current_account.companies.first
       end
      resource.update(current_company: company.id)
 end

    respond_to do |format|
      if current_user.save
       format.html { redirect_to edit_account_url(@account), notice: 'Account was successfully created.' }
       format.json { render json: @account, status: :created, location: @account }
     else
       format.html { render action: "new" }
       format.json { render json: @account.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end
```

The edit and update action are the following:

```
  # GET /accounts/1/edit
   def edit
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.js
      format.json { render json: @account }
    end
  end

 # PUT /accounts/1
 # PUT /accounts/1.json
 def update
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @account.update_attributes(account_params)
        format.html { redirect_to show_account_url(@account), notice: 'Your account has been updated successfully.'}
        format.json { head :no_content }
     else
       format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @account.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
   end
 end
```

then I call the form with:

```
<% if current_user.accounts.first.present? %>
   <li class="list-group-item"><%= link_to "Account data",edit_account_path(current_user, @account) %></li>
 <% end %>
```

Routes are as follows:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  authenticated :user do
     root 'pages#home', as: :authenticated_root
  end
    root 'pages#index'

  devise_for :users,
          path: '',
          path_names: {sign_in: 'login', sign_out: 'logout', edit:  'profile', sign_up: 'registration'},
          controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: 'omniauth_callbacks',  registrations: 'registrations'}

resources :accounts
...
end
```

I receive the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AccountsController#edit
Couldn't find Account with 'id'=2.
```

where the `id` is the `user id`.

after update 1. the error is now:

```
    No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"accounts", :format=>#<User id: 2, email: "test@test.com", created_at: "2018-12-11 10:51:45", updated_at: "2019-02-11 22:34:57", fullname: "Jacques", provider: nil, uid: nil, image: nil, phone_number: nil, description: "", pin: nil, phone_verified: nil, stripe_id: "", unread: 1, merchant_id: nil, activation: 2, team_id: nil>, :id=>nil, :locale=>:fr}, possible unmatched constraints: [:id]
```

I am trying to update the user account for the correct user.

Comment: try replacing `edit_account_path` to this `edit_account_path(@account, current_user)`

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. Is this linked to the order of creation of the job tables ? (a takes precedence over b ?).  However,  this returns
   ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Registrations#edit
That seem to indicate a mix up between the Devise routes (devise account class) and the Account class I created to manage users ?
my route is pretty straightforward : resources :accounts
this indicates there is a mix up between

Comment: show your routes too, why are you passing the current_user to `edit_account_path`? for it's name you should only have `@account` as the parameter or maybe `edit_account_path(current_user.accounts.first)`

Comment: Account would not work but edit_account_path(current_user.accounts.first) is working.
I now have a undefined method `show_accounts_url' for #<AccountsController:0x00007fe8268ed2b0> error.  triggered by the redirect after account update : format.html { redirect_to show_accounts_url(@account), notice: 'Your account has been updated successfully.'}

Comment: actually that should be `account_path(@account)` right? which takes to account show page.

Comment: right. that works, thanks for your help.